# Getting key value from NSDictionary with GooglePlus class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, google-plus

I have a NSDictionary called itemDict and when printing

```
NSLog(@"itemDictValues:%@",itemDict);
```

The output is in this format:

```
itemDictValues:
GTLPlusPerson 0xab821e0: 
{etag:""LTv_6IJISeUQGTVXLjMeOtebkoM/eup2crXcelmpMFKesXWlGkJjCiE"" kind:"plus#person" id:"1145282979128841" objectType:"person" displayName:"FirstName LastName" image:{url} url:"https://plus.google.com/1145282979128841"}
```

From this I need to extract the values corresponding to **id**, **displayName** and **url** to my NSString variables, in this format

```
profileId=1145282979128841;

Name=FirstName LastName;

Profilepic=https://plus.google.com/1145282979128841;
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: You say that itemDict is an NSDictionary, but it doesn't appear to be based on you saying that it's not responding to objectForKey. Can you show some code on how itemDict is getting set? Is it not in fact an NSDictionary, but instead a GTLPlusPerson?

Comment: NSMutableArray *friends=[NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary * itemDict in peopleFeed.items)
{
 SocialProfile *friend=[[SocialProfile alloc] initWithDictionary: itemDict socialMedia:kSocialMediaGooglePlus];
[friends addObject:friend];
  }

Comment: GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed, is how peopleFeed is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this ...

```
_profileId=(NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)itemDict).identifier;
_profileName= (NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)itemDict).displayName;
_profileImageURLPath=(NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)itemDict).image.url;
```

Answer (score 0):

For an NSDictionary

```
     NSString *profileId = itemDict[@"id"]
     NSString *name = itemDict[@"displayName"]
     NSString *profilePic = itemDict[@"image"][@"url"]
```

If it is GTLPlusPerson object then access the properties with objective-c dot syntax

```
     NSString *profileId = itemDict.id;
     NSString *name = itemDict.displayName;
     NSString *profilePic = itemDict.url;
```

Judging by your log, it appears it is a GTLPlusPerson object and not an NSDictionary

Comment: throws error NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLPlusPerson objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae49b60'

Comment: Im not sure of the object you are parsing. Are you parsing a NSDictionary or GTLPlusPerson?

Comment: You're getting your unrecognized selector issues because that itemDict is nil when you're attempting to access it.

Comment: @JoelFischer the output of NSLog displays data so I am assuming it is not nil

Comment: @KyleC Then it's not a dictionary. It's saying that it doesn't know what that method you're calling on it is.

Comment: @JoelFischer I agree that it is not NSDictionary, that is why I updated my answer

Comment: Actually I'm storing the response from google plus in an NSDictionary object which is itemDict and I've printed out its log using NSLog to show u guys how it looks like. The dictionary contains the GTLPlusPerson class.

Comment: And the objective-c dot syntax doesnt work, it says property not found during compile.

Answer (score 0):

You just parse the Dictionary to get your desired information.

```
NSString *profileId = [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *displayName = [itemDict objectForKey:@"displayName"];
```

Now that image, I think that's in a dictionary itself. And since you haven't specified what's inside that dictionary, so here's what I think you should do:

```
NSDictionary *imageDict = [itemDict objectForKey:@"image"];
NSURL *imageURL = [imageDict objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Then getting the UIImage becomes pretty straightforward :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:imageURL];
NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

You should choose the sendAsynchronousRequest method as it happens in the background and doesn't hold up the functionality of your app.

Comment: NSString *profileId = [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"] doesnt work, throws NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLPlusPerson objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae49b60'

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* peopleList = peopleFeed.items;
NSLog(@"peopleList %@ ",peopleList.description);
for (NSArray *dict in peopleFeed.items) {
                    NSString *peopleStrID=(NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)dict).identifier;
                    NSLog(@"peopleStrID %@",peopleStrID);
                    NSString *peopleName = (NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)dict).displayName;
                    NSString *peoplePic = (NSString*)((GTLPlusPerson*)dict).image.url;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the code Google provides:

```
    if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
        // The user is signed in.

        GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];


        GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
            plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

        //auth = GTMOAuth2Authentication object from login          

        [plusService setAuthorizer:auth];

        [plusService executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                    } else {
                        // Retrieve the display name and "about me" text
                        NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", person.displayName, person.aboutMe];
                        NSString *imageURL = person.image.url;

                    }
                }];



    } else {
        //user is logged out
    }
}
```